# Making includegraphics placement conditional on width of graphic

Tags: graphics, adjustbox

As shown in the MWE below, I am using graphicsx in conjunction with adjustbox. I have a document with many figures and would like to automate the "inner" (as opposed to "center") placement of figures that exceed the textwidth. I have spent a lot of time with LaTeX but this is beyond me and my searches for a solution have been fruitless so far. Thanks for any help!

P.S. My MWE probably could be more minimal but I have included all packages I use in this document that have anything to do with floats or graphics.

```
\documentclass[
   paper=8.5in:11in,
   BCOR=0.5in,
   twoside=true
]{scrbook}
\areaset[0.5in]{5in}{8in}
\addtolength{\voffset}{0.5in}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0.5in}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1in}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[figurename=Example]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{newfloat}

%% Adjust box adds "inner" and "center" options to includegraphics
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

I would like to match the behavior of this:

\begin{figure}[h!t]
    \includegraphics[scale=1,inner]{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}

    \includegraphics[scale=0.5,center]{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}
\end{figure}

\newpage
Here:

\newcommand*{\myincludegraphics}[2]{%
    \includegraphics[#1,center%% some conditional argument
    ]{#2}%
}

\begin{figure}[h!t]
    \myincludegraphics{scale=1}{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}

    \myincludegraphics{scale=0.5}{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could be `\myincludegraphics{scale=1, inner}{example-image-16x10}` a solution?

Comment: No, I want LaTeX to assess the width of the graphic and then position accordingly. The MWE is just an illustration; in reality, I have hundreds of floats and I want to automate the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly use `\makebox`:

```
\documentclass[
   paper=8.5in:11in,
   BCOR=0.5in,
   twoside=true
]{scrbook}
\areaset[0.5in]{5in}{8in}
\addtolength{\voffset}{0.5in}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0.5in}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1in}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[figurename=Example]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newsavebox{\igbox}
\newcommand{\igdecide}{%
  \ifdim\wd\igbox<\textwidth
    c%
  \else
    \ifoddpage
      l%
    \else
      r%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\fincludegraphics}[2][]{%
  \par
  \sbox\igbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \checkoddpage
  \makebox[\textwidth][\igdecide]{\usebox{\igbox}}%
}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\begin{figure}[!ht]

\fincludegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}
\captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}

\fincludegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}
\captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}

\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[!ht]

\fincludegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}
\captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}

\fincludegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}
\captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I recompile your code now the images are smaller!? Maybe I created them with a different density on update of the `mwe` package...

Comment: @MartinScharrer I changed the code to use `width` rather than `scale`.

Comment: That what I did as well. I have to check on the images in `mwe` still.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[
   paper=8.5in:11in,
   BCOR=0.5in,
   twoside=true
]{scrbook}
\areaset[0.5in]{5in}{8in}
\addtolength{\voffset}{0.5in}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0.5in}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1in}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[figurename=Example]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{newfloat}

%% Adjust box adds "inner" and "center" options to includegraphics
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

% customizing LaTeX innards. Still possible, for the time being.
\makeatletter
\def\bm@IC{\hss\edef\width{\dimexpr\the\width\relax}%
           \ifdim\width>\linewidth
             \ifoddpageoroneside\kern\dimexpr\width-\linewidth\fi
          \fi
           \unhbox\@tempboxa
           \ifdim\width>\linewidth 
             \unless\ifoddpageoroneside\kern\dimexpr\width-\linewidth\fi
           \fi
          \hss}

\newcommand*{\myincludegraphics}[2][]{%
    {\parindent\z@ \parfillskip\z@skip\checkoddpage
     \makebox[\linewidth][IC]{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}\par}%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\mainmatter

I would like this behavior :

\begin{figure}[h!t]
    \myincludegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}

    \myincludegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[h!t]
    \myincludegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}

    \myincludegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[h!t]
    \includegraphics[scale=1, inner]{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}

    \includegraphics[scale=0.5, center]{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[h!t]
    \includegraphics[scale=1, inner]{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}

    \includegraphics[scale=0.5, center]{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: the `\edef\width{\dimexpr\the\width\relax}` is because the `\unhbox\@temboxa` empties the box register, and `\width` which is macro `\wd\@tempboxa` does not work after it. I could have done `\unhcopy`, or a solution using a temp dimen, there are many ways.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution based on `adjustbox` using `precode` key. Unfortunately it is not possible to do this with a single call of `\adjustimage` as the `\width` key then does hold not yet the new scaled width but the original one. Therefore nesting the `\includegraphics` or `\adjustbox` inside `\adjustbox` is required.

```
\documentclass[
   paper=8.5in:11in,
   BCOR=0.5in,
   twoside=true
]{scrbook}
\areaset[0.5in]{5in}{8in}
\addtolength{\voffset}{0.5in}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0.5in}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1in}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[figurename=Example]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{newfloat}

%% Adjust box adds "inner" and "center" options to includegraphics
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\begin{document}

\mainmatter

I would like to match the behavior of this:

\begin{figure}[h!t]
    \includegraphics[scale=1.2,inner]{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}

    \includegraphics[scale=0.5,center]{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}
\end{figure}

\newpage
Here:

\newcommand*{\myincludegraphics}[2]{%
    \adjustbox{precode=%
        \ifdim\width>\textwidth
            \expandafter\innersidebox
        \else
            \expandafter\centerbox
        \fi
    }{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}

\begin{figure}[h!t]
    \myincludegraphics{scale=1.2}{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}

    \myincludegraphics{scale=0.5}{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}
\end{figure}

\newpage
And here:

\begin{figure}[h!t]
    \myincludegraphics{scale=1.2}{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}

    \myincludegraphics{scale=0.5}{example-image-16x10}
    \captionbelow{Captions always centered on textwidth}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```